# Is it possible to make todonotes package use margin outside pagetrim for draft notes?

Tags: memoir, todonotes, marginnote, draft

In the `memoir` manual there is a snippet for making draft notes that uses the entire paper when printing drafts on pages bigger than the trimmed papers. Is it possible to get the more fancy notes of the `todonotes` package to use that margin space as well? I think the readability of white on magenta as in this example is much higher and I really like to have the line provided by the `todonotes` package as well.

If the `todonotes` package can't do it, is there some other alternative in order to get my dream-behavior? :)

```
\documentclass[svgnames,showtrims, 10pt, draft]{memoir}

\usepackage[textsize=small, linecolor=magenta, bordercolor=magenta,
            backgroundcolor=magenta]{todonotes}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{white}\oldtodo{\textsf{#1}}}}

\stockaiv
\settrims{30mm}{25mm}
\trimFrame
\settrimmedsize{242mm}{165mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{*}{25pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{5.5pc}{6pc}{*}
\setcolsepandrule{1pc}{0pt}
\setmarginnotes{12pt}{6pc}{24pt}
\setsidecaps{2pt}{6.5pc}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\sideparmargin{outer}
\strictpagecheck
\checkandfixthelayout

%% A new command that allows you to note down ideas or annotations in
%% the margin of the draft. If you are printing on a stock that is wider
%% than the final page width, we will go to some length to utilise the
%% paper that would otherwise be trimmed away, assuming you will not be
%% trimming the draft. These notes will not be printed when we are not
%% in draft mode.
\makeatletter
\ifdraftdoc
\newlength{\draftnotewidth}
\newlength{\draftnotesignwidth}
\newcommand{\draftnote}[1]{\@bsphack%
{%% do not interfere with settings for other marginal notes
\strictpagecheck%
\checkoddpage%
\setlength{\draftnotewidth}{\foremargin}%
\addtolength{\draftnotewidth}{\trimedge}%
\addtolength{\draftnotewidth}{-3\marginparsep}%
\ifoddpage
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{\draftnotewidth}%
\marginpar{\flushleft\textbf{\textit{\HUGE !\ }}\small #1}%
\else
\settowidth{\draftnotesignwidth}{\textbf{\textit{\HUGE\ !}}}%
\addtolength{\draftnotewidth}{-\draftnotesignwidth}%
\marginpar{\raggedleft\makebox[0pt][r]{%% hack around
\parbox[t]{\draftnotewidth}{%%%%%%%%% funny behaviour
\raggedleft\small\hspace{0pt}#1%
}}\textbf{\textit{\HUGE\ !}}%
}%
\fi
}\@esphack}
\else
\newcommand{\draftnote}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem ipsum}%
\sidepar{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\lipsum[1]
\todo{Fix the: Nam dui ligula, fringilla}
\lipsum[2]
\draftnote{Fix the: Nulla malesuada porttitor diam}
\lipsum[3-5]
\sidepar{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\lipsum[6]
\todo{Fix the: Nam dui ligula, fringilla}
\lipsum[7]
\draftnote{Fix the: Nulla malesuada porttitor diam}
\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

- Added more lipsum to make it two pages
- Added `\sidepar` to show that margin notes that are not draft notes should be on the trimmed page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `textwidth` option of the `todonotes` package to specify the size of the margin note.  Usually would just increase the size of marginpars, after your page set-up for `memoir`, but if you don't want to change that dimension, it is possible to rewrite some of the internals from the `todo` package, hiding the width of the `todo` notes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[svgnames,showtrims, 10pt, draft]{memoir}

\usepackage[textsize=small, linecolor=magenta, bordercolor=magenta,
            backgroundcolor=magenta, textwidth=5cm]{todonotes}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\LetLtxMacro{\oldtodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{white}\oldtodo{\textsf{#1}}}}

\stockaiv
\settrims{30mm}{25mm}
\trimFrame
\settrimmedsize{242mm}{165mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{*}{25pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{5.5pc}{6pc}{*}
\setcolsepandrule{1pc}{0pt}
\setmarginnotes{12pt}{6pc}{24pt}
\setsidecaps{2pt}{6.5pc}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\sideparmargin{outer}
\strictpagecheck
\checkandfixthelayout

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline=-0.75ex]%
    \node [coordinate] (inText) {};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\marginpar[{% Draw note in left margin
    \@todonotes@drawMarginNote{r}%
    \@todonotes@drawLineToLeftMargin%
}]{% Draw note in right margin
    \@todonotes@drawMarginNote{l}%
    \@todonotes@drawLineToRightMargin%
}%
}
\renewcommand{\@todonotes@drawMarginNote}[1]{
    \makebox[\marginparwidth][#1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline=(X.base)]%
        \node(X){\vphantom{X}};%
        \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
            {\@todonotes@text};%
        \if@todonotes@authorgiven%
            \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                {\@todonotes@sizecommand\@todonotes@author};%
            \node(Y)[below=of X]{};%
            \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.south)%
                {\@todonotes@text};%
        \else%
            \draw node[notestyle,font=\@todonotes@sizecommand,anchor=north] (inNote) at (X.north)%
                {\@todonotes@text};%
        \fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem ipsum}
\sidepar{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\lipsum[1]
\todo{Fix the: Nam dui ligula, fringilla}
\lipsum[2]
\todo{Fix the: Nulla malesuada porttitor diam}
\lipsum[3-5]
\sidepar{\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}}
\lipsum[6]
\todo{Fix the: Nam dui ligula, fringilla}
\lipsum[7]
\todo{Fix the: Nulla malesuada porttitor diam}
\lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat, but it only works on the first page. On the next page the margin is on the left side and increasing the textwidth places the todo note on top of the other text. Updated the example code to use two pages.

Comment: Hm that seems scary, isn't that thing used for other stuff when setting the page which will be problems for the ``not draft notes'' things? I will test.. :)

Comment: Updated the example to reflect needed features that I didn't think of when designing it.

Comment: I see.  I have now posted a new approach that rewrites some internals of the `todo` package instead.

Comment: Very nice! I feel that only accepting and moving on is not thanks enough... This seems to be exactly what I was dreaming about!